# Configuring Relodium python plugin to watch only the current file and not the entire project

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, hook, watch

I need to use hot reloading to change the function along the run. I have found a beautiful plug in called Relodium
https://reloadium.io/documentation/intro

They have even specified how to configure it to load only the files that I want it to watch instead of complete project folder (which also contains log files)
The link is given below.
https://reloadium.io/documentation/config-file

Can  someone please tell how to use these files to configure the plugin to watch only the current file and not the entire folder